# wordpress site not rendering correctly on mobile for any theme

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, themes, rendering

I am new to wordpress, 10 days to be exact, My website does not render correctly on mobile devices no matter which theme i use. It displays strange i.e. some css issue and at the end is a button to switch to web view... when i click web view then it renders correctly.

Apparently web version works fine and responsive but mobile version which loads by default on mobile devices is not rendering correctly.
I have tried deactivating all plugins, switching between different themes, installing/uninstalling wptouch and jetpack, checking page source for viewport issues etc but of no use. I did not create this site but I am asked to fix this issue.

At the moment I am not using any plugin for responsiveness, theme is responsive.

url to the website : http://www.locksmithsdubai.com

let me know if you want to see code of any file from my wordpress site.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: point noted... i'll be careful in the future

Comment: i think i found something suspecious in .htaccess file, copy pasting the suspicious portion:  
# stop condition
RewriteRule ^mobile/.*$ - [L]
#Redirect urls based on a query string parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?view=mobile([^&]*)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?m%1%3 [CO=is_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},CO=disable_mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m*(.*&)?view=full([^&]*)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [CO=disable_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]                                                                                     if someone know how to edit .htacces